# Android Sqlite insert blob

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

I'm trying to insert a blob which includes only 0 and 1. But it isn't working.
First I'mm getting a bitmap, converting to binary image. After that I want to insert to database as blob. But the database's row is empty. 
Here the code is;

```
        Otsu(retpix,picw,pich);
        byte[] byteimage = new byte[length << 2];
        for (int di=0; di<144; di++) {
             int x = retpix[di];
             int j = di << 2;
             byteimage[j++] = (byte) ((x >>> 0) & 0xff);           
             byteimage[j++] = (byte) ((x >>> 8) & 0xff);
             byteimage[j++] = (byte) ((x >>> 16) & 0xff);
             byteimage[j++] = (byte) ((x >>> 24) & 0xff); 
         }
        String PutName = "imagearray";
        cv.put(PutName, byteimage);
        db.insert("IMAGES", null, cv);
        db.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not Base64 encode your bitmap (or any byte array) and insert that instead. SQLite prefers text.